# Relative Motion Question - Inparticular method

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, relative-motion

Here is my question:
Aircraft  A  is  travelling 
West  and  aircraft  B is flying  in  a  circular,  anti-clockwise  holding pattern of 2km radius at 400 km/h. When ‘B’ is pointing South, the pilot of ‘A’ sees aircraft ‘B’ which relative to him/her, appears to be travelling at 600 km/h.

(a) Calculate the speed of ‘A’and the direction of the relative velocity.

(b) At  that  instant, ‘A’ and ‘B’ lose sight of each other and 30 seconds later they crash. Estimate  the  collision  position  and how  far  apart  they  were  when  they  lost  visual contact.

---

For part a) i got 447.03 km/h

I am unsure in what you do for part b). I made an attempt however i had to use an unfamiliar equation for this part of the calculation and i need conformation if it correct and why it is correct to use.[image]

My question is, why was $pi$ added to the equation when calculating the angle for aircraft B at the collision?
Could someone provide a clear explanation.

Comment: On part "b", did the aircraft crash into each other while traveling in the air?

Comment: Yes in the air. They crash into each other after 30 seconds once they lose sight of each other

Comment: Keep in mind i haven't provided my entire solution. This is just an initial calculation for part b). However why would use pi?